# Gradle: create zip file containing classes and dependencies

Tags: gradle

I have to create a zip-file containing the classes (and the manifest etc.!) in a `classes`-folder and the dependency jar-files in an `libs` folder. My current attempt is:

```
task createZip(type: Jar) {
   into('classes')
   extension('zip')
   with jar
}
```

but it does not add the dependencies (as anyone would have guessed)

Comment: i only use gradle as a build tool and have no knowledge of groovy.

Comment: Isn't that what the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) does?

Comment: i have run it and it creates a zip, but not with the needed schema

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, i solved it

```
task plugin(type: Zip) {
    from (configurations.compile) {
        into ('libs/')
    }
    from (sourceSets.main.output.classesDir) {
        into ('classes/')
    }
    from (sourceSets.main.resources) {
        into ('classes/')
    }
    from (new File(project.buildDir, 'tmp/jar/')) {
        into ('classes/META-INF/')
    }
}

plugin.dependsOn jar
```

this copies the dependencies into libs and all the compiled classes, resources and the manifest into libs. `plugin.dependsOn jar` is important because the manifest ist generated by the jar task.

Answer (score 1):

Your question says you desire a zip file, though your attempt uses a Jar task.  Regardless of whether you zip or jar (since the jar task extends zip), the below snippet will collect all compiled dependencies, and you can put them wherever you desire:

```
from (configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) })
```

Comment: i need the dependency jar-files. i don't know what i get with this, but not the jar files (some extracted classes i guess)

Comment: Yeah, that collects extracted classes from the jars.